# How to convert into a single mesh

Tags: modifiers

With the boolean modifier, I have made a union between two meshes with this result:

[image]

.. including this face, where the meshes intersected:

[image]

Any suggestion or help to make this into a single solid mesh, with thickness to its walls?

[image]

Comment: It **is** a single solid mesh! It's not at all clear what you are expecting to see.

Comment: Hi, @atek Do you mean something like [this](https://blend-exchange.com/b/9gWsSZVy/) i.e. a manifold mesh with a flat skin on the inside? Please edit your question to make it a bit clearer what you want to wind up with. If this is it, I / others will pop in an answer.

Comment: What do you want to see? The edges? You can't see any other edges on the mesh in _Object Mode_ either.

Comment: @RobinBetts yes how u did it may i know?

Comment: @atek See edit to Gordon's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect to see **this** in *Object Mode*,

[image: inside bulge]

you have to <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* and select the inner face:

[image: select inner face]

Then delete it with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete* > *Faces*

[image: delete face]

Et voilà:

[image: removed face]

To take it further, and create a single, manifold mesh:

[image]

Delete the little flange, which will be surplus to requirements, give the mesh a *Solidify* modifier, and apply it. But the inside isn't flat..

[image]

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-Select and delete the connecting loop to make the remaining unwanted inner faces easier to select with hover- <kbd>L</kbd>, delete those, too..

[image]

Select the boundary of the hole, and <kbd>F</kbd> Fill. The result, below, has <kbd>X</kbd> > Dissolved Faces to unify the flat inner skin at the back, and then  <kbd>J</kbd> reconnected the vertices top and bottom to restore the mirror-line, in case it's needed.

[image]

Comment: No, not in that way, @robin has given the answer in the comment, plz have a look above

Comment: @atek Well, as he also commented: please edit your question to make clearer what you want.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann hope you don't mind the edit.. I didn't want to pull the 'Reopen' trick on you again :)

Comment: @RobinBetts Haha :D No, I don't mind... when I thought about doing the solidifcation I also did exactly the same thing after applying the modifier: selecting the edge loop of the bulge, deleting it, then L for the remaining rest to delete it ;)